# How can I modify my docker-compose.yml file so I can access a specific file in a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have the following docker-compose.yml

```
  pivpn:
    privileged: true
    image: ljishen/pivpn:amd64
    container_name: pivpn
    ports:
     - "443:443/udp"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/myContainer/ovpns:/home/pivpn/ovpns
```

I'm using portainer to login to the console of this container and I can execute the following which will show me the contents of a file.

```
cat /etc/pivpn/setupVars.conf
```

I want this file to be accessible via a volume, so I can edit it, recreate a container, etc.  I've tried adding the following:

```
  - ${USERDIR}/myContainer/conf:/etc/pivpn
```

But when I check the container logs when starting I get the following:

> ./run: line 25: /etc/pivpn/setupVars.conf: No such file or directory

Without the mount, the container will create the file.  But with the mount, the file won’t be created.  So having that mount kind of puts me in a catch-22 situation.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Copy the file from the container to your host first, with no volume set up. Then move the file to your on-host volume, and relaunch the container with the volume configured.

Comment: Since I can't accept an answer, anyone who is browsing this in the future should know this worked -- kinda.  The image behaves funny, but I was able to mount and see this file

Comment: You can always write your own answer, WhiskerBiscuit - it is encouraged here `:-)`